# ParseObject.collectFetchedObjects() throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, exception, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and I get this exception quite randomly from time to time. Problem is that I do not know what is causing this to happen? Anyone knows what triggers the call to "ParseObject.collectFetchedObjects()"? And what could be the cause of the ConcurrentModificationException? 
Here is the important part of the stack trace:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:838)
at com.parse.ParseTraverser.traverseInternal(ParseTraverser.java:87)
at com.parse.ParseTraverser.traverse(ParseTraverser.java:137)
at com.parse.ParseObject.collectFetchedObjects(ParseObject.java:817)
at com.parse.ParseObject.access$700(ParseObject.java:49)
at com.parse.ParseObject$13.then(ParseObject.java:1487)
at com.parse.ParseObject$13.then(ParseObject.java:1484)
at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"ParseObject.collectFetchedObjects()"
```

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only to detect bugs.

from the docs

please check number of threads running and make synchronised.

Comment: Thank you. I have actually read this and tried to make my Maps synchronised. Problem is that I do not know which map Throws this, and I also suspect that its a underlying Parse method that I actually do not call myself that is triggering the "coolectFetchedObjects". Since I do not know which method its difficult to figure out where the error is located. I have tried to check my threads for when I modify what, but without any luck so far. Also tried to make all my HashMaps to ConcurrentHashMaps, still no luck

Comment: I think I was able to fix it be making some changes to the threads, and what called what. I do think I was accessing a object while it was in the process of saving it in a another thread. It works now at least. Problem was that I did not see any lines numbers, just like the general Exception catcher that showed the exception, but not the line where it occurred. That was what made it so difficult to solve